# Which statistical test best suits for analysing my data?

Tags: r, anova

I have a simple question. I have seven groups of experimental data like treated (Triplicate) and one control group. Here, I have three variables for each group 1. Body mass, Liver weight and bacterial load. I got confused regarding test to use. I was thinking Two way - ANOVA suits but some one said use MANOVA which is new for me. So, I am asking experts help here. Please suggest me which test I need to use for better interpretation. Please help me ASAP

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the 3 variables response (Y) variables?

Comment: I suggest GLM or GEE

Comment: Nope not response variables, third variable is independent variable, while second variable is dependent on first. Gung..

Comment: Thank you, GLM seems plausible model but still fingers crossed

Comment: How about K-S test?